# Reloading or refreshing WebBrowser control and Form in general

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I have `Form` with programatically created controls. One of them is `WebBrowser` which displays captcha image. User then inputs the captcha in the textbox and if it is wrong the form is supposed to refresh with new captcha image. I tried `Form.Refresh()` then calling `DisplayCaptcha()` again, but it didn't work so I solved it like in this (simplified) code:

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{

    public Form3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DisplayCaptchas();
    }

    private void DisplayCaptcha()
    {
        string captcha = "<style>html, body{{padding:0; margin:0 }}</style>" + 
            "<img src=\"http://www.reddit.com/captcha/{0}.png\"></img>";


            WebBrowser webBrowserNofap = new WebBrowser();
            webBrowserNofap.DocumentText = String.Format(captcha, iden);
            ......//rest of the code


    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (wrongCaptcha)
        {
            this.Close();
            Form3 form3 = new Form3(); //this is how I solved the refreshing
            form3.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Form4 form4 = new Form4();
            this.Close();
            form4.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

It works, but this is not real refreshing. I was thinking to remove controls then `DisplayCaptcha()` again, but don't know how to do that.
In short, is there any other solutions beside closing then reloading `Form`?

Comment: Can't you call the Refresh method on the WebBrowser control?

Comment: where? if I call id in DisplayCaptcha(); it's not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.Navigate("about:blank");
            webBrowser1.Document.Write("<html><head><style>html, body{{padding:0; margin:0 }}</style></head><body><div id='divMain'>&nbsp;</div></body></html>");
        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            int number = 0;
            number = r.Next(0, 999999);
            string captcha = "<img src=\"http://www.reddit.com/captcha/{0}.png\"></img>";

            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("divMain").InnerHtml = string.Format(captcha, number);
        }
    }
}
```

Everytime you click the button, you should get a new image. You can put this where you want to refresh.

Comment: it shows only blank when trying to implement in my DisplayCaptchas() method, but normally it works. I didn't know you can use it like Javascript.